# rpc.statd running on system not using NFS

Tags: debian, nfs, services, socket, daemon

I have a Debian machine that gets warnings (via the Tiger automatic auditor) that `rcp.statd` is listening on such-and-such socket. Googling shows `rpc.statd` is a daemon used by NFS. As far as I know, I'm not using (and have not installed) anything related to NFS.

What would have installed/started this service, and what do I need to do to disable the appropriate `rcp.statd` and NFS daemons?

Answer (score 15):

> What would have installed/started this service

**The debian installer**.
I was also surprised to find it enabled because

1. I did not ask for it
2. I was not told it would have been running
3. It is a security risk
4. Not many people use NFS nowdays

> and what do I need to do to disable the appropriate rcp.statd and NFS daemons?

**This**:

```
update-rc.d nfs-common disable
update-rc.d rpcbind disable
```

Reboot or issue the following commands to stop the daemons the debian way

```
service nfs-common stop
service rpcbind stop
```

Finally to verify which TCP ports are open issue the following

```
netstat -lntp
```

Comment: With systemd in debian 8 `systemctl disable nfs-common`, `systemctl disable rpcbind`, `systemctl stop nfs-common`, `systemctl stop rpcbind`. Though systemv version still works.

Answer (score 13):

by default NFS is enabled you can remove packages:

```
apt-get --purge remove nfs-kernel-server nfs-common portmap
```

or stop services temporary:

```
/etc/init.d/portmap stop
/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server stop
```

or stop them permanently:

```
service portmap stop
service nfs-kernel-server stop
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it was enabled by default. Does the `service` command exist on Debian? I thought it was only for RedHat-based systems (and then for stopping services temporarily, not permanently).

Comment: I don't seem to have `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server` on my server, how can I stop `rpc.statd`?

Comment: Run `apt-get remove --purege rpcbind`.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu, I have done this:

sudo netstat -tulpn

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
...     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      681/rpcbind
```

Uninstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove rpcbind
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove rpcbind
```

Then double check if still running:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```