# What is rpc.statd, what ports should it be listening on, and how to kill it?

Tags: debian

I have found `rpc.statd` running from a `netstat -tunap` command, on several ports (TCP:59061, UDP:40594, UDP:919) on my Debian server.

I believe it's to do with NFS but I'm not running an nfs server (AFAIK!).

([Another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20356/rpc-statd-running-on-system-not-using-nfs) mentions this problem, but the packages referred to there don't exist on my system.)

So what ports should it be running on, and if I don't need it (I connect to an NFS share, but I don't serve any) how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

find the full patch of the version of rpc.statd that is running, and get it's md5sum.  compare that to the md5sum of a known good debian server, to make sure that it's even really `rpc.statd` that's running, and not some sort of trojan.  Once you find that path to the file, you can `chmod -x /path/rpc.statd` to prevent it from executing again, or you can remove it if you know you're not running NFS.

Comment: Good tips, Tim. I found the binary in `/sbin/rpc.statd` and its md5 matches that of one I found in the .deb file which I downloaded on a separate machine and unpacked. (phew). So assuming it's OK, do I need this in order to access an nfs share on another machine?

Comment: Yes.  The NFS client will use rpc.statd and portmapper, both.